# Program is hanging after input

Tags: c

The program is supposed to read numbers that are entered and determine if they are even or odd.
Then it needs to display the odd and even count, and the averages of the numbers entered. It stops when `0` is entered.

My problem is that it just hangs after the first number entered.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void)
{
    int oddcount = 0, evencount = 0; /* Count of even and odd numbers. */
    int number;
    float avge = 0, avgo = 0;        /* Average for even and odd numbers.  */
    int evennum = 0, oddnum = 0;

    printf("Enter a number or enter 0 to stop: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &number);
    while(number != 0)
    {
        if(number % 2 == 0)
        { evencount = evencount + 1;
            evennum += number; }
        else
        { oddcount = oddcount + 1;
            oddnum += number; }
    }

    if(oddnum != 0)
        avgo = oddnum / oddcount;   /* Finding the odd average.  */

    if(evennum != 0)
        avge = evennum / evencount; /* Finding the even average.  */

    printf("Here is the count odd %i and even %i numbers.\n", oddcount, evencount);
    printf("And their averages %f odd and %f even.\n", avgo, avge);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a `while(number != 0)` loop.  If a user enters a number that is not zero how will that loop ever exit?

Comment: Look at shekhar suman's answer, it will solve your problem.

Comment: this line: scanf_s("%i", &number); is not reading an integer.  Perhaps you meant: scanf_s("%d", &number);  however, that does not consume the '\n' generated when the user presses the enter key after typing the first number.  suggest using: scanf_s(" %d", &number); which will consume white space then get the number.  Also, during the loop, no more numbers are being entered so number is never being updated.  So the loop never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't reading new numbers in after the first one.  Try something like

```
while( scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number != 0){
//Count evens and odds
}
```

Another way you could handle this would to be to add another scanf at the end of your while loop

Comment: That was awesome the program runs just as I wanted it too! Thank you so much

Comment: @ChrisHoward This does indeed work. There are other ways to solve it, like adding the reading into the while loop (and it's then required to initialize the number variable first). Might be good to know for your further studies :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an infinite loop...

```
while(number != 0)
{
    if(number % 2 == 0)
    { evencount = evencount + 1;
        evennum += number; }
    else
    { oddcount = oddcount + 1;
        oddnum += number; }
}
```

Here,your while-loop guiding variable `number` never gets modified in-between the iterations which keeps it unchanged and hence,the while condition remans true for-ever...

***Probable solution*** seems to be :-

```
int number=1;     // just for initialisation with a non-zero number...
while(number != 0)
{
  printf("Enter a number or enter 0 to stop: ");
  scanf_s("%i", &number);
    if(number % 2 == 0)
    { evencount = evencount + 1;
        evennum += number; }
    else
    { oddcount = oddcount + 1;
        oddnum += number; }
}
```

Comment: This *probable solution* doesn't solve the problem of *"hanging"* of the program.

Comment: This is likely what the author asks for (adding a break if number is 0 might look nicer). +1

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy The code (while not having tested it for syntax) is otherwise correct. It does also solve the "hanging", with which the author meant he couldn't input new numbers. This allows the author to input 0 to exit the loop, just as intended.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy-Go learn programming first and then jump here to judge answers and downvote them. Also,it is running perfectly fine in my system!

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy-Man,it's working fine. Why should I debug it unless it troubles me? Are you making out a fool of me or the reverse?

Comment: @shekharsuman,don't want to make out a fool of anyone. I just understood the question incorrectly, thought both mine and your solutions are correct in their own way (at least, when I understood the author's question correctly).